# Python while loop keeps shortening my list! Why?

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a while loop that I use to access the items of a list. I never [intentionally] alter the contents of the list, but somehow that list is shortened on every iteration through the loop! I have no idea why or where this happens. Because of this shortening, my 'list index' becomes out of range because the list is no longer its original size.

Why/where is this shortening happening?

```
# email_to = { sw: [person1, email1, person2, email2, ..] }
for sw, contacts in email_to.items():
    number = len(contacts)
    number = number-1
    i = 0
    while i < number:
       print "All items in contacts: ", contacts  # <------- 'contacts' keeps getting shorter!!? WHY!?
       recipientName = contacts[i]
           if recipientName in contactsDict[sw]:
               print recipientName, "is a contact"
               affiliationType = "C"
           elif recipientName in developersDict[sw]:
               print recipientName, "is a developer"
           else:
               print recipientName, "is of unknown affiliation"
       recipientEmail = contacts[i+1]
       i += 2

       #If I remove this part below, the rest of the code works and the list is not altered ????
       other_recipients = email_to[sw]
       receiver = recipientName
       receiverIndex = other_recipients.index(receiver)
       receiverEmail = other_recipients[receiverIndex+1]
       if receiver in other_recipients:
           other_recipients.remove(receiver)
           other_recipients.remove(receiverEmail)
```

Comment: is not the answer to your question but why don't use `for recipientName in contacts` ?

Comment: hmmm, looking back, I'm not sure. I suppose I could. I think I was worried about deleting recipientName from the list so I was trying to make a copy instead. But, good suggestion, I can trim it down now that I know where my true mistake was!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the first line below your comment

```
 other_recipients = email_to[sw]
```

You're not copying that list, you're just making another reference to it.  This means the call to `remove` affects your original list as well. If you intend for `other_recipients` to be a copy of `email_to[sw]`, then you must explicitly copy it

```
other_recipients = list(email_to[sw]) # or email_to[sw][:]
```

---

A quick example demonstrates this behavior

```
>>> a = [1,5,7]
>>> b = a
>>> b.append(99) #appends to b
>>> a # a now has 99 as well
[1, 5, 7, 99]
>>> a.remove(1) # removes from a
>>> b # b loses 1 as well
[5, 7, 99]
```

You can use the `is` operator to show that they are the same object

```
>>> a is b
True
>>> c = list(a)
>>> c is a
False
```

Comment: aaaah wow, I didn't realize that. Thank you so much! Like you said, I thought I was making a copy.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me @ryanhaining! I was definitely looking at it as a copy rather than a reference.

Comment: @steph mutability is one of the few tricky parts about the language.  Once you realize that it follows reference semantics and not value semantics, it's a bit easier.  even if the types are ints `a = b` just assigns a reference.  With ints, however, you can't call modifying methods on them, `a = a + 1` makes a refer to `a` different int.

Answer (score 1):

```
for sw, contacts in email_to.items():
    ...
    other_recipients = email_to[sw]
    ...
    other_recipients.remove(receiver)   # here you change your list
    other_recipients.remove(receiverEmail)
```